# Laravel 5.8 Slug 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to use slug but it's returning 404 Not Found. I checked the routes and it seems al right. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am taking slug as one of the inputs from the user. When the user inputs the slug, the user type in the format `product-name` and then submit.

Controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $product = Product::all()->toArray();
        return view('front.shop.index', compact('product'));
    }
    public function product(product $slug) {        
        return view('front.shop.single-product', compact('slug'));
    }
}
```

Model

```
{
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return $slug;
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'our-products'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
        Route::get('/{$slug}', 'ProductController@product')->name('single-product');
    });
```

Blade file

```
<a href="{{ route('single-product', $item['slug']) }}" title="">{{ $item['product_name'] }}</a>
```

Comment: What is the model for products named Product or product? Type hinting the model class name correctly is required for implicit route model binding.

Comment: And what are you returning on the getRouteKeyName function, send like that would actually result in an error since $slug is undefined. You need to return the slug version of the model name, `return Str::slug($this->name);` (assuming it's the name property you want to work with)

Comment: I figured our where I went wrong. In my model I was returning `$slug` whereas it should be `'slug'`. It is working perfect now.